# Fortran77 Procedure <> called with an implicit interface [-Werror=implicit-interface]

Tags: fortran, gfortran

In my fortran77 project, I call the subroutine `BDET` in the subroutine `MATS`. However the get the following error:

```
Procedure <BDET> called with an implicit interface [-Werror=implicit-interface]
```

I don't understand why this happens! `BDET` subroutine is declared before `MATS`, why is the implicit interface problem happening here?

Any help is greatly appreciated (F77 newbie here).
Thanks in advance.

```
      SUBROUTINE BDET(mat_A, DET)
C    This subroutine calculates the determinant of a 3x3 matrix
      IMPLICIT NONE
      REAL*8 DET
      REAL*8 mat_A(3,3)

      DET = mat_A(1,1) * mat_A(2,2) * mat_A(3,3) -
     1      mat_A(1,2) * mat_A(2,1) * mat_A(3,3)

      DET = DET + mat_A(1,2) * mat_A(2,3) * mat_A(3,1) +
     1       mat_A(1,3) * mat_A(2,1) * mat_A(3,2) -
     2       mat_A(1,1) * mat_A(2,3) * mat_A(3,2) -
     3       mat_A(1,3) * mat_A(2,2) * mat_A(3,1)
      RETURN
      END SUBROUTINE BDET

      SUBROUTINE MATS(DFGRD0,DFGRD1)

C  Implicitly declare variables and set character length
      IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)
      CHARACTER*80 CMNAME
      REAL*8 DFGRD1(3,3)

      REAL*8 Ibar1, Ibar2, J
      REAL*8 F(3,3)

      CALL BDET(F, J)

      RETURN
      END SUBROUTINE MATS
```

Comment: Because you haven't declared an explicit interface.

Comment: (Note that all interfaces in F77 are implicit, so using `-Werror=implicit-interface` for F77 code is unhelpful. Fortunately, gfortran isn't a F77 compiler.)

Comment: And fortunately the above is not Fortran77 code; code according to that standard should not have been written this millennium. And it's not just because of the non-standard, non-portable, should never be used real*8; ignoring that it's at least Fortran 90.